# How do I use COUNT, COUNTIF or SUM in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got an employee table and I'm trying to get a list of division ids where there are no active employees.

My first attempt was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DivisionID
FROM Employees
WHERE COUNT(IsActive = 0) = 0
GROUP BY DivisionID
```

But Count doesn't allow expressions, even though intellisense says it does.

So then I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DivisionID
FROM Employees
WHERE SUM(CAST(IsActive AS INT)) = 0
GROUP BY DivisionID
```

But then it complains "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

This seems like it should be straight forward, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Try having instead of where. After the group by clause

Comment: The where clause is used to filter rows. The Having clause is used to limit aggregated rows.

Comment: Note that the `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, since that's the column you're grouping by. By definition, you'll only get back distinct IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `having` you can filter the records you group by using a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT DivisionID
FROM Employees    
GROUP BY DivisionID
HAVING sum(case when IsActive = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: No, it might not.

Comment: `IsActive` column is not in `group by` clause. then, How can we use that in `having` clause. What I have understood from error phrase. Else, Are am I need to know about the `having` clause?

Comment: It is in an aggregation function -> `sum()`

Comment: yeah.. It was correct. I facing this case as first time. Thx a lot @juergen

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this does what you want:

```
SELECT DivisionID
FROM Employees
GROUP BY DivisionID
HAVING MAX(IsActive) = 0
```

Comment: Hope the Max function will slow down the query as the records grow?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed . . . No.  The `GROUP BY` affects performance.  This should be the simplest way to do what you want.

Comment: Note that this requires a conversion if `IsActive` is a `BIT`, since, in their infinite wisdom, the engineers decided not to allow `MAX` on `BIT`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DivisionID
from (
    SELECT DivisionID, count(*) as tmpcount from Employees WHERE IsActive=0 group by 
    DivisionID 
) 
WHERE tmpcount>0
```